# Firestore orderBy and where filters not working together

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

If I query my `users` collection and filter by 2 different properties as seen below, it returns the expected data.

```
return this.afs
  .collection<Employee>('users', ref => {
    return ref
      .where('accountId', '==', accountId)
      .where('isEmployee', '==', true);
  })
  .valueChanges()
```

However, if I try to order that data by `name`, as seen below, it returns an empty array.

```
return this.afs
  .collection<Employee>('users', ref => {
    return ref
      .where('accountId', '==', accountId)
      .where('isEmployee', '==', true)
      .orderBy('name');
  })
  .valueChanges()
```

I figured I must need to manage the way indexing is being handled or something, but did some research and my understanding is that if that were the case, I would get an error message in the console with a link to setup the composite indexing that I need. I don't get any errors though, just an empty array. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to order a collection of data that is filtered by 2 properties? I believe I am using Firebase version 6.5, but am willing to update if that will solve my problem.

Comment: Firestore indicates https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data. 
However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=),
your first ordering must be on the same field. Does ordering by accountId return an empty array?

Comment: Yes, it still returns an empty array if I order by accountId instead of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would get an error message in the console with a link to setup the composite indexing that I need.

Yes, that's correct. When you are using a query like yours, a warning message should be displayed in the console.

> I don't get any errors though, just an empty array.

In this case, you should create that index manually in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

> Is it possible to order a collection of data that is filtered by 2 properties?

Sure it is. Just create the required index and then you should be able to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t look like you’re ready to catch errors. May want to do something like:

.catch(error => console.log(error)

(Will format that when on desktop)